# Is it possible to have minimap zoomed out by default?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

I find myself pressing <kbd>M</kbd> to zoom out the minimap in the beginning of every round because I prefer to see the whole picture on the minimap rather than a surrounding area. Is there a way to have the minimap zoomed out by default?